# get a socket for a given ip address and port in vba for winsock

Tags: vba, ms-access, tcp, winsock

I need to be able to send a simple string message to a tcp address (eg 127.0.0.1:123456) from inside MS access vba.

I have found this example using winsock which looks like it should work, and after changing the scope to private for the functions enums and types it compiles, but I have no idea how to get a socket for an ip address and port number.

Below is the code but its not clear how to get a socket id from an ip address and port number in order to use this.

```
Const INVALID_SOCKET = -1
Const WSADESCRIPTION_LEN = 256

Enum AF
  AF_UNSPEC = 0
  AF_INET = 2
  AF_IPX = 6
  AF_APPLETALK = 16
  AF_NETBIOS = 17
  AF_INET6 = 23
  AF_IRDA = 26
  AF_BTH = 32

End Enum

Enum sock_type
   SOCK_STREAM = 1
   SOCK_DGRAM = 2
   SOCK_RAW = 3
   SOCK_RDM = 4
   SOCK_SEQPACKET = 5
End Enum

Enum Protocol
   IPPROTO_ICMP = 1
   IPPROTO_IGMP = 2
   BTHPROTO_RFCOMM = 3
   IPPROTO_TCP = 6
   IPPROTO_UDP = 17
   IPPROTO_ICMPV6 = 58
   IPPROTO_RM = 113


End Enum

Type sockaddr
   sa_family As Integer
   sa_data(0 To 13) As Byte
End Type
 
Type sockaddr_in
  sin_family As Integer
  sin_port As Integer
  sin_addr(0 To 3) As Byte
  sin_zero(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type


'typedef UINT_PTR        SOCKET;
Type socket
   pointer As Long
End Type



' typedef struct WSAData {
'  WORD           wVersion;
'  WORD           wHighVersion;
'  char           szDescription[WSADESCRIPTION_LEN+1];
'  char           szSystemStatus[WSASYS_STATUS_LEN+1];
'  unsigned short iMaxSockets;
'  unsigned short iMaxUdpDg;
'  char FAR       *lpVendorInfo;
'} WSADATA, *LPWSADATA;

Type LPWSADATA_Type
   wVersion As Integer
   wHighVersion As Integer
   szDescription(0 To WSADESCRIPTION_LEN) As Byte
   szSystemStatus(0 To WSADESCRIPTION_LEN) As Byte
   iMaxSockets As Integer
   iMaxUdpDg As Integer
   lpVendorInfo As Long
End Type

'int errorno = WSAGetLastError()
Public Declare Function WSAGetLastError Lib "Ws2_32.dll" _
   () As Integer
   
'   int WSAStartup(
'  __in   WORD wVersionRequested,
'  __out  LPWSADATA lpWSAData
');
Public Declare Function WSAStartup Lib "Ws2_32.dll" _
    (ByVal wVersionRequested As Integer, ByRef lpWSAData As LPWSADATA_Type) As Long



'int sendto(
'  __in  SOCKET s,
'  __in  const char *buf,
'  __in  int len,
'  __in  int flags,
'  __in  const struct sockaddr *to,
'  __in  int tolen
');
Public Declare Function sendto Lib "Ws2_32.dll" _
    (ByVal socket As Long, ByRef buf() As Byte, _
     ByVal length As Long, ByVal flags As Long, _
     ByRef toaddr As sockaddr_in, tolen As Long) As Long


'    SOCKET WSAAPI socket(
'  __in  int af,
'  __in  int type,
'  __in  int protocol
');

Public Declare Function f_socket Lib "Ws2_32.dll" Alias "socket" _
    (ByVal AF As Long, ByVal stype As Long, ByVal Protocol As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function closesocket Lib "Ws2_32.dll" _
    (ByVal socket As Long) As Long
    
Public Declare Sub WSACleanup Lib "Ws2_32.dll" ()
Sub main()
Dim ConnectSocket As socket

Dim wsaData As LPWSADATA_Type
   
   
Dim iResult As Integer
   iResult = 0

Dim send_sock As sock_type
  send_sock = INVALID_SOCKET
    
Dim iFamily As AF
   iFamily = AF_INET
    
Dim iType As Integer
   iType = SOCK_DGRAM
   
    
Dim iProtocol As Integer
   iProtocol = IPPROTO_UDP
   
Dim SendBuf(0 To 1023) As Byte
Dim BufLen As Integer
   BufLen = 1024
   
Dim RecvAddr As sockaddr_in
RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET
RecvAddr.sin_port = 23
RecvAddr.sin_addr(0) = 192
RecvAddr.sin_addr(1) = 168
RecvAddr.sin_addr(2) = 1
RecvAddr.sin_addr(3) = 30


SendBuf(0) = 65
SendBuf(1) = 66
SendBuf(2) = 67
SendBuf(3) = 0

   

iResult = WSAStartup(&H202, wsaData)
If iResult <> 0 Then
   MsgBox ("WSAStartup failed: " & iResult)
   Exit Sub
End If


send_sock = f_socket(iFamily, iType, iProtocol)
    
If send_sock = INVALID_SOCKET Then
   Errno = WSAGetLastError()
   Exit Sub
End If

iResult = sendto(send_sock, _
  SendBuf, BufLen, 0, RecvAddr, Len(RecvAddr))
If iResult = -1 Then
   MsgBox ("sendto failed with error: " & WSAGetLastError())
        closesocket (SendSocket)
        Call WSACleanup
        Exit Sub
End If


iResult = closesocket(send_sock)
If iResult <> 0 Then
   MsgBox ("closesocket failed with error : " & WSAGetLastError())
   Call WSACleanup
End If

End Sub
```

Can anybody explain how I can use this to send a string message?

Comment: The code you provided does exactly that (well, it sends a binary buffer, which is a lot more well-defined than a string). Which part of this code are you struggling with?

Comment: The lines following `Dim RecvAddr As sockaddr_in` set the port (23) & IP address (192.168.1.30) - what else do you need?

Comment: This code is already sending a string (`"ABC\0"`). If you want to make that more flexible, you just need to add some extra code to convert characters from a `string` into a `byte()` array.

Comment: However, you are not populating the `RecvAddr` struct correctly. Use `htons()` to assign the `sin_port`, and use [`inet_addr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wsipv6ok/nf-wsipv6ok-inet_addr) or [`inet_pton()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_pton) to assign the `sin_addr`. Or better, use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) and let it allocate a properly populated `sockaddr_in` for you.